# react-native get selection text start and end from text component

Tags: react-native, text, getselection, react-native-textinput

I used Text component reference: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html

with property `selectable={true}`, is there any solution to get the user text selection start and end on `Text` component not `TextInput` component?

because I need to make the text selectable with editable false.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this https://github.com/Astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text/

```js
import { SelectableText } from "react-native-selectable-text";

// Use normally, it is a drop-in replacement for react-native/Text
<SelectableText
  menuItems={["Foo", "Bar"]}
  onSelection={({ eventType, content, selectionStart, selectionEnd }) => {}}
  value="I crave star damage"
/>;
```